# NSFetchedResultsController Date Predicate Not Working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` that needs to fetch an entity that has an `NSDate` property.

Using the standard iOS template code for a fetched results controller, I am setting the predicate to be `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date == %@", date]`.

This predicate works perfectly when the objects are new, but when they change, this doesn't work. Here's the flow:

1. Create new object with the correct date that satisfies the predicate. The FRC will call the delegate and everything works as intended.
2. Quit the app, come back to the view where the FRC is setup, use a new date to set the predicate. No objects found - again, as intended.
3. Fetch and save the object with the correct date that satisfies the new predicate. The delegate method is not called.

Here's the thing: I'm not changing the predicate at all (or the date that is passed into the predicate format string), but if I reset the predicate and reload the tableView then the predicate loads fine. Also, if I leave the view and come back, same thing. I can even leave the view and come back and it works fine. This is because the fetched results controller delegate isn't being called.

Thanks in advance,
James

Comment: It sounds like you may be using one `NSManagedObjectContext` for for the NSFRC and another to perform the change. It also sounds like your contexts are both directly attached to a `persistentStoreCoordinator`, rather than set up as parent/child contexts. Is that the case?

Comment: Are you using `NSSortDescriptor`, and if so, could you please show the code?